# bootstrap different height of nesting columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a tricky (for me) problem using nesting columns with bootstrap.

What i want to reach is an team gallery which has

1. on md,lg -> 1 row 4 columns with picture and the name underneath.
2. on sm -> 2 rows with 2 columns with picture and the name underneath.
3. on xs -> 4 rows 2 columns with picture in the left column und the name in in the right column

To reach this i use nested columns and it works very well except one important thing: -> on xs should have the right column with the name the same height as the left column with the image because i want to middle the the name vertical to the image. Unfortunately all my trys didn't help (display: table-cell, height: 100%, etc.)

i attachted my actual code and result to make my problem visual.

HTML:

```
<section id="about" class="section about2">
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/team/wimmer_matthaeus.png" alt="Matthäus Wimmer" /></div>
                        <div class="namecell col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h4>Matthäus Wimmer</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/team/kragl_gerhard.png" alt="Gerhard Kragl" /></div>
                        <div class="namecell col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h4>Gerhard Kragl</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/team/mayr_manuel.png" alt="Manuel Mayr" /></div>
                        <div class="namecell col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h4>Manuel Mayr</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/team/anton_riegler.png" alt="Anton Riegler" /></div>
                        <div class="namecell col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h4>Anton Riegler</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            </div>      
        </div>
    </section>
```

LESS/CSS:

```
.about2 {

  .row
  {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }     

  img
  {
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   border:3px solid @color;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: @color;

     &:hover
     {
       border:3px solid @color;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background: #fff;
       transition: 1s;
     }
   }

  .namecell
  {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
  }

  h4
  {
    text-align: left;
  }
```

}

[correct result on md, lg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giDqi.png)

[wrong result on xs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkIRo.png)

Comment: Use `@media` query and set `height` in pixels.

Comment: Is there no other way than use static pixel height?

When i set the height in px i will loose my generic growth of the images and in worst case the images get taller than the div container cause img-reponsiv class

Answer (score 0):

You could provide some top padding to the `<h4>` tags only for small devices. Media queries is the optimal solution to add the styles specific to device widths.

Just add this to your existing styles.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .namecell > h4 {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

I have created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxQMZa)

Answer (score 0):

Hy everbody,

thanks 4 your ideas.

This solves my problem:

i had to style my inner-rows with this and it works:

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items:center;">
```

Here the link who brings me to my answer:
http://howtocenterincss.com/#contentType=div&horizontal=left&vertical=middle&browser.IE=none